# Multiple Errors with read_csv in pandas / python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to the data analytics programming topics or programming in general and need to use pandas in university. I don't understand the error messages yet and am looking for help.
I was trying to read the .csv file we're supposed to use but got multiple error.

## My Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\julius\OneDrive\UNIVERSITÄT\Master\3. Semester\Fallstudie BA\KFZ_BelegPrf.csv")
df
```

## My errors:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\juliu\Desktop\KFZ_BelegPrf.csv")
      2 df

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:912, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, date_format, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options, dtype_backend)
    899 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    900     dialect,
    901     delimiter,
   (...)
    908     dtype_backend=dtype_backend,
    909 )
    910 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 912 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:577, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    574 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
    576 # Create the parser.
--> 577 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    579 if chunksize or iterator:
    580     return parser

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1407, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
   1404     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
   1406 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
-> 1407 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1679, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1676     raise ValueError(msg)
   1678 try:
-> 1679     return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
   1680 except Exception:
   1681     if self.handles is not None:

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py:93, in CParserWrapper.__init__(self, src, **kwds)
     90 if kwds["dtype_backend"] == "pyarrow":
     91     # Fail here loudly instead of in cython after reading
     92     import_optional_dependency("pyarrow")
---> 93 self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
     95 self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
     97 # error: Cannot determine type of 'names'

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:550, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:639, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:850, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:861, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._check_tokenize_status()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:2021, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 6625: invalid continuation byte
```

I've tried changing the encoding to `latin 1` but got another error:

```
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\juliu\OneDrive\UNIVERSITÄT\Master\3. Semester\Fallstudie BA\Fallstudie BA WS2324.ipynb Cell 3 line 1
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\juliu\OneDrive\UNIVERSITÄT\Master\3. Semester\Fallstudie BA\KFZ_BelegPrf.csv", encoding='latin1')

File c:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:912, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, date_format, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options, dtype_backend)
    899 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    900     dialect,
    901     delimiter,
   (...)
    908     dtype_backend=dtype_backend,
    909 )
    910 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 912 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File c:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:583, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    580     return parser
    582 with parser:
--> 583     return parser.read(nrows)

File c:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1704, in TextFileReader.read(self, nrows)
   1697 nrows = validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
   1698 try:
   1699     # error: "ParserBase" has no attribute "read"
   1700     (
...

File c:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:2029, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8 fields in line 5, saw 9
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I am afraid, without seeing the data it would be difficult to diagnose what's wrong. Could you share some of the data at least the first several hundred rows? The first error occurred at position 6625, so it is probably a few hundred rows from the head.

Comment: Have you tried to convert the csv into a different encoding? Like, you could just iconv it to utf8

Comment: With the ISO-8859-1 encoding and changing the separator to semicolon it worked... Well that was easier than expected. I was just overwhelmed by the amount of error messages.

Answer (score 1):

With the `ISO-8859-1` encoding and changing the **separator to semicolon** it worked... Well that was easier than expected. I was just overwhelmed by the amount of error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your problem is wrong encoding, try to figure out the csv text encoding using [this site](https://online-decoder.com/ru/ei)

Comment: yes as written in my comment above I forgot to change the separator and tried a different encoding.